# Get following letter from given

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with company names. Some companies have different locations and different legal names but they should be reported under the same Group Code. The Code is made up using the first five letters.

```
Company         GroupCode
DEEZER FRANCE   DEEZE
DEEZER SPAIN    DEEZE
DEEZER ALGERIA  DEEZE
```

So far so good. Now I’m adding a different company which starts with the same letters but should get a new Group Code.

A new Code should be assigned if the company name does not contain a word which is part of a company name already having a GroupCode. In this Case     `DEEZER` is the key word which determines association with GroupCode `DEEZE`

Rule is that the code should then use the first four letters + the fifth letter next in the alphabet. If this code also exists then use the first four letters + the fifth letter next but one in the alphabet. The required result would look like:

```
Company         GroupCode    Status 
DEEZER FRANCE   DEEZE        EXISTING
DEEZER SPAIN    DEEZE        EXISITNG
DEEZER ALGERIA  DEEZE        EXISTING
DEEZEMBER       DEEZF        CREATED
DEEZEMAL        DEEZG        CREATED
```

So what I need to figure out is the next „unused“ letter. How can I achieve this with SQL Server 2008 R2?

Comment: How do you indicate that DEEZEMBER is a different company from the 3 DEEZER companies? Is there any field to do that?

Comment: @shree.pat18 There is `Status` field.

Comment: @shree.pat18 I added some explanation on how GroupCodes are assigned. Hope that helps

Comment: What's the rule for if the code should, naturally, be `ZZZZZ` but that code is already taken by a different company?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
;with cte as
(select max(groupcode) maxcode
 from yourtable 
 where left(code,4) = left(@companyname,4))

insert into yourtable (company, groupcode, [status])
select @companyname,
case when maxcode is null then left(@companyname,4) + 'a' else left(maxcode,4) + char(ascii(right(maxcode,1))+1) end,
'created'
from cte
```

Assumption: Your input is taking the company name as a parameter from somewhere, presumably the front end.

The idea is to use `ascii` function to get the ASCII code of the last letter, increment it by 1 and go back to the corresponding character using `char` function.

Be warned, however, that this is definitely not the best solution. For instance, I have not implemented bounds checking to ensure range between A and Z. In fact, I would suggest that you handle this in application code rather than at DB level.

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction. The `ASCII`function did the trick.